# Remote editing of a SpringSource application on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm working on a project currently up and running on a Tomcat 6 install and coded with SpringSource.

I downloaded STS, but I don't understand how I get my STS installation to edit the files on that server rather than the ones in my workspace?

I'm finding it hard to code without the real-time help and debugging from the actual SpringSource IDE.

I've searched SO and Google--I'm sure I'm not the only one who's wondered how to do this--so I assume maybe there's a technical name for doing this I'm not using in my search terms?

It's a noob question, I'm a front end developer, so I embrace my text editors.

Thank you.

Comment: I have it installed on my computer already. I'm asking how do I make it work with files that are on a remote server, rather than on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you copying the edited files to the server? Are you editing them locally and then copying them to the server?

As @Shahzeb already points out, the SpringSource Tool Suite [can be downloaded for free](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts).

Comment: I was using Coda. As I've stated above. STS is installed on my machine. I have it. The issue is that I don't know how to use the IDE to edit the application already sitting on the server. I can only create "projects" on my local machine.

Comment: Sorry, I just needed my second morning coffee for my brain to start fully functioning! ;-)
Usually, Java-based web applications are developed locally, compiled, then packaged into what is called a "WAR" file and then copied to the remote server. So, usually, the **Java source files are not included in this WAR file. In the specific case of Tomcat, the WAR file is copied in the "webapps" Tomcat subdirectory. I would suggest that you check that directory to see if there is a WAR file there.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rafael. I'm fading myself. It's 2am here.